# Duplicar linha da Grid

Tags: genexus

Estou querendo implementar na tela padrão de uma transação de 2 níveis um botão de duplicar registro . O componente Grid por padrão já possuí o botão para excluir a linha da grid.

Já criei a tela inteira na mão e a grid fiz baseada em uma SDT, porém a performance da tela cai consideravelmente, porque tenho algumas fórmulas e campos referenciados, que utilizando a SDT tenho que carregar tudo na mão.

Na imagem em anexo está exemplificando o que estou querendo. Penso que talvez tenha que usar alguma rotina JavaScript ou C#.

GxEv2 .Net - MySql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Não tem uma boa forma de implementar isso no Grid da transação, em transação, acho que melhor forma seria criar um UserControl para o Grid, [UserControl CustomRender](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?11850),

Porem sugiro fazer em WebPanel, com variáveis ou SDT sem problemas de performance, se tiver problemas não estará relacionado a esta funcionalidade de duplicar, dependendo que como é a sua tela, pode ser revisado para melhorar a performance,

Comment: Boa tarde, não tenho conhecimento sobre o desenvolvimento de usercontrol, mas é o que poderia resolver. Com relação a SDT, realmente o problema de performance não é com o duplicar, mas sim com o carregamento de automático de alguns campos, ex: "Valor do produto", depois de selecionar busca o preço do produto. "Nome do cliente", depois de colocar o ID do cliente busca o nome. Desde já Agradeço a sua Ajuda.

Comment: De fato, se você tem uma tela muito grande, fica lento mesmo ficar atualizando alguns campos automáticos, uma solução seria utilizar o UserControl [AJAX Caller](https://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?ajaxcaller,pt), porem se não implementado bem, pode gerar mais problemas,

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, vou verificar esse UserControl.